# pointer c++ explanation

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am confused with this block of code:

```
ipPtr = ipPtr + 3; // 5
cout << *ipPtr << endl;
```

Why the `cout` is not 5 but some random large number? can anyone explain to me please. As my understanding I thought the `cout << *ipPtr << endl;` is pointed to the `*ipPtr` above it. Am I right ?

```
#include <iostream>

void main(){
    using namespace std;
    int iaArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int* ipPtr = 0;

    ipPtr = &(iaArray[1]);
    cout << *ipPtr << endl;//2

    ++ipPtr;
    cout << *ipPtr << endl;//3

    ipPtr = ipPtr + 3; //not 5 but random number. 
    cout << *ipPtr << endl; 
}
```

Comment: You are pointing beyond the end of the array. The array size is 5, and you are pointing at the 6th element that's why you are getting some random number. 2 + 1 + 3 = 6 not 5 :)

Comment: Any chance you're going to accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 8):

Because you have incremented the pointer past the end of the array.  You seem to have forgotten that you wrote `++ipPtr` before adding 3 to it.

```
          &(iaArray[1])
               |
iaArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } ?
                  |         |
               ++ipPtr  ipPtr + 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you add 3 to the pointer it's already on the third position of the array, so it ends up after the last element.

Answer (score 0):

```
ipPtr = &(iaArray[1]);
```

//Pointing to the second position (first one is 0)

```
++ipPtr;
```

//Pointing to the third position

```
//3 + 3 = 6
ipPtr = ipPtr + 3;
```

The array only has 5 positions so it prints whatever is in that memory location not 5 which is in the fifth position.